# UriFormatException was unhandled

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have XML document returned from web service which I am transforming into another XML document using `xsl schema`. I am getting an error
`'UriFormatException was unhandled. Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.'` But I am able to get the required XML document if I save the `SampleReportXML` in  the temp folder and read it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       string inputXML =     @"C:\TEMP\SampleReport.xml";  
       string transformXSL = @"C:\TEMP\TransformSchema.xsl";   

       XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       xslt.Load(transformXSL);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = false;
        XmlWriter swriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
        xslt.Transform(inputXML, null, swriter);
        sb.Append(writer.ToString());
        writer.Close();
        sb.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");
        TextReader textReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        doc.Load(textReader);
        return doc;


       XmlDocument SampleReportXML = new XmlDocument();
       SampleReportXML = WS.getReport(100);  //passing the parameter value to get the report XML doc from Web service
       string inputXML = SampleReportXML.InnerXml.ToString();
       string transformXSL = @"C:\TEMP\TransformSchema.xsl";


       XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       xslt.Load(transformXSL);

        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = false;
        XmlWriter swriter = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings);
        xslt.Transform(inputXML, null, swriter); //getting error here
        sb.Append(writer.ToString());
        writer.Close();
        sb.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");
        TextReader textReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
        doc.Load(textReader);
        return doc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply want to pass the `SampleReportXML` as the first argument to the transform method. Currently you are serializing the document to a string and then you pass in the string to a method which expects a Uri.